# Sum if cells contain a range of multiple comma separated values (From another cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of *attacks* together with *powers*. I want to get the total sum of  all *powers* which matches multiple comma separated values in another cell.

This is how my first sheet looks like:

## Sheet 1

```
| Attack               | Power         |
|:---------------------|:--------------|
| nuke                 | 300           |
| nuke and laser       | 500           |
| megalasernuke        | 1000          |
| fist                 | 10            |
| weak fist and bow    | 50            |
| supreme fist and bow | 100           |
```

## Sheet 2

Using `=SUMIF('Sheet1'!A:A;"*"&A2&"*";'Sheet1'!B:B)` in column B, my second sheet can return the sum of all power containing **one** value:

```
| Attack               | Sum of Power  |
|:---------------------|:--------------|
| nuke                 | 1800          |
| fist                 | 160           |
```

I want to be able to sum if the cells in Sheet1 contains **multiple** comma separated values (all of them), resulting in the following:

```
| Attack               | Sum of Power  |
|:---------------------|:--------------|
| nuke,laser           | 1500          |
| fist,bow             | 150           |
| fist,bow,nuke        | 0             |
| fist                 | 160           |
```

Is this possible to do without custom excel scripts?

Comment: so you want an AND relationship not an OR on the comma list?

Comment: Yes! Sum if cells contains `nuke` AND `laser`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not pretty but I can't figure another method, as you want to iterate twice:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),1,99)),$A$2:$A$7))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)),$A$2:$A$7))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),198,99)),$A$2:$A$7))*$B$2:$B$7)
```

This only works up to three comma separated values.

[image]